# How to use several matrixParam?

Tags: rest, spring-rest

I would like to get my controller handle request with variables like this:  `manager/sorted/;isbn=12312323;added_date=12.12.12`

I have a controller:

```
@GetMapping("/sorted/{isbn},{addedDate}")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getSortedBooks(@MatrixVariable(name = "isbn", pathVar = "isbn") String isbn,
                                                     @MatrixVariable(name = "addedDate", pathVar = "addedDate") String addedDate) {    

        return response;
    }
```

But is doesn't work. I've looked spring docs https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-matrix-variables, but there no any example with handle several variables one by one.

How can I handle this case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I guess your code should looks like

```
@GetMapping("/sorted/")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Book>> getSortedBooks(@MatrixVariable(name = "isbn", pathVar = "isbn") String isbn,
                                                     @MatrixVariable(name = "addedDate", pathVar = "addedDate") String addedDate) {    

        return response;
    }
```